# How can I find installed web applications?

Tags: installation, lamp, websites, drupal

I've installed LAMP Server using tasksel. I've installed phpMyAdmin, which I know from experience gets in /phpmyadmin. That works. Then I installed drupal6. I assumed that it would get in /drupal, but that's not the case.

How can I find that kind of information? Of course, in this case, I'm looking for my Drupal install, but I would like to avoid having to spend so much time every time I install a web application, so I'm looking for a generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a common way for all web applications. It depends on how they were packaged. I agree this is not ideal.

In the case of drupal6 though, the example apache2 configuration file is created as /etc/drupal/6/apache.conf.

To get drupal6 working as expected in your question, you need to

1. copy /etc/drupal/6/apache.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal6

   `sudo cp /etc/drupal/6/apache.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal6`
2. link /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/drupal6 to /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal6

   `cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

   `sudo ln -sf /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal6 .`
3. Restart apache2 for the changes to take effect.

   `sudo service apache2 restart`
4. You can then install drupal6 by visiting **http://localhost/drupal6/install.php** in a web browser.

Comment: Seems you're right. This is strange. I complained about the same thing in 2006-7, I think. I expected there'd be some improvements by now. :)

Answer (score 0):

in the gnome 3 environment you can drag the icon to the sidebar in the menu, or if you are using unity you can right click on the icon once opened in the sidebar and check pin to sidebar. but my only advice if you cant find it go to the source where you got drupal and see if it can be run from a terminal i forgot also you can possibly use the sort option which is available in both unity and gnome 3

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I wasn't talking about using web applications in the desktop, but the web applications themselves in a server install.